# Update object using REST API in Symfony2 with FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I want to update an entity with Doctrine2. I use a form to create and update entities. I want to send an object as parameters for my REST URL.

My code is like this :

```
public function putUpdateAction(Client $obj){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $serv = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AccessRhBundle:Client")
                 ->findOneBy(array('id' => obj->getId));
    $serv->setNom($obj->getNom());
    $em->merge($obj);
    $em->flush();
}
```

`#app/config/routing.yml`

```
rest:
  type : rest
  resource : clientBundle\Controller\ClientController
  prefix : /rest
```

When I call this method from my client application I get error 404 URL not found.

I try to see the debugger and the result was that url contain `No route found for "PUT /api/updateClient/[object%20Object]": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)` which is not defined.

Someone have an idea how I can send an object as parameters of a rest method in symfony?

Comment: The typo `getUodateAction` is only in this example or also in your proper code?

Comment: Can we see your annotations ?

Comment: @JulienBourdic which annotations?

Comment: @cezar I just update the method function it s **getUpdateAction** it is also in my proper code

Comment: How do you declare your routes to map with FOSRest ?

Comment: I only use the name of the function which I want to call .. `path/update/`

Comment: in the `routing.yml`I ve add this :                                                                      `rest:
       type : rest
       resource : Access\RhBundle\Controller\RhController
       prefix : /rest`

Comment: `[object%20Object]` is what you get when you do `({}).toString()`, so you're getting that bad URL from your Javascript somewhere. The second thing to note is that you're submitting a `PUT` HTTP request, but the error says only `GET` and `HEAD` are allowed.

Comment: how can I resolve the first problem ?